# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED on android studio4.2.2 with android 12 SDK

Tags: android

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl309224224.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #111): com.xx.Activity: Targeting S+ (version 10000 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]
```

try almost answer and failed. what should I do?

Comment: Please share manifest file and sorce code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I find anser: android:exported="true"

Comment: This question is same i think... it helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70333565/targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-an-explicit-value-for-android